# Flutter - How to stop Flutter from repeatedly downloading Gradle zip file and resolving fine dependencies

Tags: android, flutter, gradlew

This issue started haunting me again after upgraded to Flutter 3.0.

I getting tired with running Flutter app on multiple devices when it repeatedly keeps redownloading Gradle zip file and all those jar and pom files just because it encounters one error that occurred only because of the poor internet connection which is caused by their unresponsive server, not my internet.

I can't stand seeing it keeps redownloading a half of gigabytes files on a single occurance of poor internet connection issue, and do it again if there's error again, like everything I've downloaded before are no longer usable.

For Gradle, I know how to do it manually for example by running `gradlew --offline build` and install the files manually, but i have no idea how to do the same if the resources installation fully handled by Flutter because the error occur on dependencies resolving while building the app.

Comment: please i beg you flutter team if you read this please have it fixed. it's working fine before. right now even after managed to deploy on two devices, the error still come

Comment: I am having the same issue and it is EXTREMELY ANNOYING

Comment: i simply edit `gradlew` file and add `--offline` to the last line at the end. but that just prevent gradle from automatically trying to download the file on the background without let us know first

Comment: I have solved mine by just upgrading Android SDK from API level 29 to 32, the issue disappeared that way

Comment: i think that what i did too. the issue suddenly gone. i thought that's because flutter's new version fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to solve the Gradle problem by manually changing the
`gradle-wrapper.properties`.

You need to change the Gradle version at the end of the `distributionUrl` with a `zip` file that contains an already downloaded Gradle distribution.

For example, this case with a `gradle-7.5.1.zip`:

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1.zip`

You can check all your Gradle versions in the default folder `C:\Users\$USER\.gradle\wrapper\dists`.

If there is not a single `.zip` file in the main folder, then you have to check all the sub-folders and copy-paste it in the main folder or download it yourself.

Unfortunately this is only for Gradle distributions, there is no way to avoid downloading new dependencies. Since is all handled by the flutter package manager.